# Are there other scientific examples of lacking elements? Like cold is a lack of heat energy

Tags: magic

Cold isn't a real force, it's a lack of heat energy.  Vacuum is a lack of air.  I am working on a magic system called lack-magic.  Heartless=cold magic, voiceless=vacuum magic, etc.  Are there any other examples in science for a lack of something?

Comment: Questions asking for potentially endless lists are off topic here. And this is an example of those

Comment: @L.Dutch, while I'm not saying this is a great question, I'm not sure I can agree with its potential to be an endless list, either. The set of "physical properties" is not infinite.

Comment: can't you do this with anything, dryness-lack of water, void-lack of substance/solid, bland-lack of flavor, neutral-lack of energy/electricity, etc

Comment: @Matthew I don't know if it's definitely infinite or infinitely finite. However, I know it's too hard to determine a best answer here as of now. Is it the one that has 3 elements, one which has 8? A "random" one based solely on the reader's personal preference x)?

Answer (score 3):

### Two easy ones

Darkness: Lack of light, sightless/blind

Silence: Lack of sound, deaf

The tidbit at the end is because I assume people who have a lack of what is normal is capable of casting magic related to what they are suffering

Comment: Please answer only well asked questions